# Handling Screen Rotation for Fragment inside of View(State)PagerAdapter inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello kind (android) programmers,

The situation is as follows:

I have an activity that uses a NavigationDrawer that allows to load 3 fragments. Inside one of those fragments I have a ViewStatePagerAdapter, which on it's turn hosts 3 fragments. In one of those fragments I load a bunch of databasedata using a cursorloader. These values are editable to a new value, but should not be persisted to DB until a certain button is clicked.

All this works fine, but the problem is that when I now rotate the screen, all the changed data is gone. I tried using onSaveInstance in the inner fragment itself, but I think the problem lies higher, as I already noticed than when I rotate the screen, the viewpager jumps back to the first tab.

What would be the correct way (/correct location: activity, certain fragment,...) to:

1. Make sure the viewpager remains on the right tab
2. Remembers the data that changed in the inner fragment

The fragment that contains the viewpager currently has following onCreateView :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return v;
}
```

and an inner class for the FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
 class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return PersonFragment.newInstance();
            case 1 : return FriendsFragment.newInstance();
            case 2 : return EventsFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return int_items;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "ME";
            case 1 :
                return "FOLLOWING";
            case 2 :
                return "EVENTS";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

nothing special happening for the rest in here. (Which maybe should?)

The fragment inside of the viewpager has following onCreate/onCreateView

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_person, container, false);
    this.viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rootView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        CharSequence savedPersonName = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("personName");
        if (savedPersonName != null) {
            Log.v("PersonFragment", savedPersonName.toString());
            this.viewHolder.personnameView.setText(savedPersonName);
        }
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some code. What does your viewpager do on create? Is it getting an instance of the existing fragment, or creating a new one entirely. What is in your onCreate for the fragment.

Comment: @QuantumTiger
Coming right up, already added a part, adding more too.

Comment: Where do you reload the savedinstancestate

Comment: I no longer do, as it made the app crash the way I did it. That's why I wanted to know where and how I should do it exactly.
In the viewpager fragment, I used the onSaveInstanceState to add data to the outState bundle, and in onActivityCreated I checked if it was null, and if not, got my data out of it.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible that my data does get passed on if done like that, but that the GUI just doesn't update?

Comment: In terms of the first part of your question I can't see anything wrong with what you are doing. You are using getChildFragmentManger() (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858679/how-to-put-viewpager-inside-fragment-in-android) and your FragmentStatePagerAdapter looks fine, so I can't obvious reason for why the tab page is changing

For the second part, my experience is that you have to get the values out of the saved instance state, yourself. So the question is why when you did this did it crash. Perhaps you could re-implement that and say what the error was? It might cast some light!

Comment: Please read my answer hear http://stackoverflow.com/a/33730090/1553254

Comment: Seems like the problem was in the mainActivity yeah, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You probably know this already but this is the kind of thing I would do to address your second issue

```
private TextView tvTitle;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);

    tvTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mytitle);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      CharSequence csTitle = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("myTitle");
      if (csTitle != null) tvTitle.setText(csTitle);
    }
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

outState.putCharSequence("myTitle", tvTitle.getText());
}
```

Comment: So I did this and even sent the value to logcat, and the right value shows up in there. In the same if statement I use setText, yet I do not see it changing in the GUI.
I updated the onCreateView I use now in my original post, so you can see.

Comment: So it looks like the fragment being viewed is a different instance to the one writing to the logcat. Did Nguyen's answer above help?

Comment: I think I fixed it, I temporarily deleted some stuff though, so some bug might turn up again.

Seems like the problem was that in my mainActivity, I made a new HomeFragment every single time, instead of first checking if there was one existing (by using findFragmentByTag). I guess this made all it's children disappear too, including the ViewPager and the fragments inside of that one.

Thanks for taking the time to help me out, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Glad you found it. The whole fragment, pager thing is rather poorly documented IMHO

Comment: I tried tot found some decent documentation on how it works exactly yeah, without much succes. I guess the best way is to read it's source code...